# C Linked list - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, segmentation-fault

## Hey guys,

so im doing this doubly linked list code, compiling works.. but executing gives me SIGSEGV. When i tried running valgrind it said that there is some uninitialised values.

My best guess would be that this is happening because malloc'd memory scope reach or smthing like.. idk maybe it gets dumped when the function ends?..im not sure, but it still says that there is some memory allocated and reachable...or maybe there is just some semantic error that im not aware of :/

### valgrind --track-origins=yes out:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14798==    at 0x400848: push (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==    by 0x40088E: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==14798==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14798==    by 0x400879: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)

==14798== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14798==    at 0x4E8476B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==14798==    by 0x4E8812C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1631)
==14798==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==14798==    by 0x400793: printlist (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==    by 0x4008CD: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==14798==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14798==    by 0x400879: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)

==14798== Invalid write of size 8
==14798==    at 0x40071B: pop (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==    by 0x4008D9: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

==14798== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==14798==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==14798==    at 0x40071B: pop (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==    by 0x4008D9: main (in /home/mename/linkedlist/llist)
==14798==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0==14798== 
==14798== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14798==     in use at exit: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==14798==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 2 frees, 1,144 bytes allocated
==14798== 
==14798== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14798==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14798==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14798==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14798==    still reachable: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==14798==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

#### edit:

added other functions and their libs (pop; clearlist; *.h)
changed/updated files as answers suggested

---

### clearlist.h

```
#ifndef CLEARLIST_H
#define CLEARLIST_H

#include "defs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int clearlist(node** head);

#endif
```

### pop.h

```
#ifndef POP_H
#define POP_H
#include "defs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int pop(node** head);

#endif
```

### printlist.h

```
#ifndef PRINTLIST_H
#define PRINTLIST_H

#include "defs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int printlist(node* head);

#endif
```

### push.h

```
#ifndef PUSH_H
#define PUSH_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defs.h"

int push(node** head, int datainput);

#endif
```

### defs.h

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE -1
#define ALLOCFAIL -2
#define EMPTY -3

typedef struct Node{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
    int data;
} node;
#endif
```

### main.c

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "clearlist.h"
#include "pop.h"
#include "printlist.h"
#include "push.h"

int main(){
    node *head;
    head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    push(&head, 10);    
    push(&head, 20);    
    push(&head, 30);    
    push(&head, 40);    

    printlist(head);

    pop(&head);

    printlist(head);

    clearlist(&head);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I will show just the functions involved until core dump which i think are responsible for the errors.

### push.c

```
#include "push.h"

int push(node** head, int datainput){

    /* Initialization of new node */
    node* newptr = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));    
    if(newptr == NULL){
        return ALLOCFAIL;
    }
    newptr->next = NULL;
    newptr->data = datainput;

    /* Check for empty list */
    if(head == NULL){
        newptr->prev = NULL;
        *head = newptr;
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /* Get to the end of list*/
    node* headptr = *head;
    while(headptr->next != NULL){
        headptr = headptr->next;        
    }

    headptr->next = newptr;
    newptr->prev = headptr;
    return SUCCESS;
 }
```

### printlist.c

```
#include "printlist.h"

int printlist(node* head){
    /* Check if valid node or empty list */
    if(head == NULL){
        return EMPTY;
    }

    /* Move to first node if not already */
    node* firstptr = head;
    while(firstptr->prev != NULL){
        firstptr = firstptr->prev;
    }

    /* Print entire list*/
    while(firstptr != NULL){
        if(firstptr->next != NULL){
            printf("%d -> ", firstptr->data);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", firstptr-->data);
        }
        firstptr = firstptr->next;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

### pop.c

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "pop.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int pop(node** head){

    /* If no node to pop */
    if(*head == NULL){
        return EMPTY;
    }
    /* Get to the end of list */
    node* headptr = *head;
    while(headptr->next != NULL){
        headptr = headptr->next;        
    }
    /*Pop last*/ 
    node* temp = headptr->prev;
    free(headptr);

    /* po temp - Check if deleted the only node left*/
    if(temp = NULL){
        *head = NULL;
        return EMPTY;
    }
    /* ...if not, make previous node the last node  */

    temp->next = NULL;
    headptr = NULL;

    return SUCCESS; 
}
```

### clearlist.c

```
#include "clearlist.h"

int clearlist(node** head){
    if(*head == NULL){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /* Go to start */
    while((*head)->prev != NULL){
        *head = (*head)->prev;
    }
    /* Delete to the end */
    while(*head != NULL){
        node *prevnode = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(prevnode);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

---

### Thanks for all your help!

I dont really want to ask for a full solution, i want to learn something new but im a bit stuck on this one.
:)

Comment: Compile with the `-g` flag and valgrind will be able to point you to specific line numbers in your code.

Comment: Also, I don't see `#include <stdlib.h>` so the compiler might be treating `malloc()` as returning an `int` instead of a pointer. This can cause the return value to not be a valid pointer (which can definitely happen on 64-bit targets). But perhaps that was left out of the posted code?

Comment: i included stdlib.h in push.h, i dont think that would cause this issue

Comment: We are unable to reproduce your problem with out an extensive rewrite of your code.  This is because the code uses several 'home grown' header files that were omitted from the post.  Those header files are: `#include "clearlist.h"
#include "pop.h"
#include "printlist.h"
#include "push.h"`

Comment: the posted code is calling `pop()`  but there is no such function in the posted code.  similar considerations exist for the function: `clearlist();

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in general, when a C library function fails, the code should output an error message to `stderr`,  This is easily performed by calling `perror()`  which will output the enclosed text AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: in the main() function there is: `node *head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));`  This places a node, containing trash, into the linked list.  Strongly suggest replacing those two statements with: `node *head = NULL;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `malloc`ing doesn't initialize anything, for example:

```
node *head;
head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

The values of the node could be anything, you need to set the pointers to NULL

```
head->prev = head->next = NULL;
```

Further, you should declare and initialize the node on a single line and **don't cast the result of malloc**, I'd also recommend the other `sizeof` mechanism. There is a more robust way to zero-initialize everything in the `node` if you are in C99 or later which is to use a composite literal

```
node* head = malloc(sizeof *head);
*head = (node){0};
```

Looking through the rest of your code I'm not positive if this is the same problem everywhere, but you should be following the above pattern for your own safety.

Comment: So in this case, i could either initialize it as you said, or dont malloc in advance and just set the pointer to null?

Comment: you have to allocate otherwise you'd be calling `push` with a NULL pointer if you do your latter suggestion.

Comment: yeah but i thought that push will initialize the pointer, right?
Why shouldnt i cast the result, i thought it only helps?

Comment: @RollAndSchullz read this: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: C passes arguments by value. The `head` variable inside `push()` is not the same as the `head` variable in `main()` (though it might initially have the same value).  Changes made to `head` inside `push()` are lost when it returns.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz [I wrote this one a while ago](https://medium.com/@ryanhaining/how-to-malloc-the-right-way-c-476375d53745)

Comment: @RyanHaining Maybe you should add an answer to the above question with a link to your page. We prefer to link to SO questions rather than external sites.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I meant to tag OP in that last comment

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
int main(){
    node *head;
    head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    push(head, 10);

    ...

}
```

`head` is only allocated, it is not initialized!

When you pass that not initialized pointer to `push`,

```
 if(head == NULL)
```

will be false and the block is not going to be executed, however the next block

```
node* headptr = head;
while(headptr->next != NULL){
    headptr = headptr->next;        
}
```

is executed. Remeber `head` is not initialized, so `headptr->next` points to
nowhere and you assign `headptr = heatdptr->next` and so on.
Valgrind is telling you this: *Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation*

The `push` function should take a double pointer to `head` and change where it's
pointing to when a new head is created:

```
int push(node **head, int datainput){
   /* Initialization of new node */
   node* newptr = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));    
   if(newptr == NULL){
       return ALLOCFAIL;
   }
   newptr->next = NULL;
   newptr->data = datainput;

   /* Check for empty list */
   if(*head == NULL){
       newptr->prev = NULL;
       *head = newptr; // change where head is pointing to
       return SUCCESS;
   }

   /* Get to the end of list*/
   node* headptr = *head;
   while(headptr->next != NULL){
       headptr = headptr->next;        
   }

   headptr->next = newptr;
   newptr->prev = headptr;
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
int main(){
    node *head = NULL; // <-- important initialization

    push(&head, 10);
    push(&head, 20);
    ...
}
```

Also note: [don't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

---

**edit**

The `printlist` has also a small errror, you are only printing the head, the
correct version should be

```
int printlist(node* head){
    /* Check if valid node or empty list */
    if(head == NULL){
        return EMPTY;
    }

    /* Move to first node if not already */
    node* firstptr = head;
    while(firstptr->prev != NULL){
        firstptr = firstptr->prev;
    }

    /* Print entire list*/
    while(firstptr != NULL){
        if(firstptr->next != NULL){
            printf("%d -> ", firstptr->data);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", firstptr->data);
        }
        firstptr = firstptr->next;
    }

    puts("");

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that C does not have *pass by reference*, so if you want to modify a value
of a variable in other function, you pass a pointer to that variable:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    *p = 8;
}

void bar(void)
{
    int c = 4;

    foo(&c);

    // c is now 8
}
```

That same applies to pointers, if you want to change where a pointer is pointing
to in another function, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer (aka double
pointer):

```
void foo(char **str)
{
    *str = "World";
}

void bar(void)
{
    char *x = "Hello";
    puts(x); // prints Hello

    foo(&x);

    // x points now to a different string literal

    puts(x); // print World
}
```

That's what I'm doing in `push`.

To prove that this is correct, see this: https://ideone.com/As5XDy

I've used my `push` function (and the fix of `printlist`) and the output is

```
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40
```

Also don't forget to write a function that frees the memory.

Comment: yeah, now i initialized the pointers to NULL, but it still says that there is sigsev ;(

Comment: @RollAndSchullz I've edited m answer and added a fix to your `push` function.

Comment: Yeah but, in your code, wouldnt i point then at the head address and not the node address?
btw thanks very much! :)

Comment: @RollAndSchullz I don't understand what you mean. The head is just a node object, it's the first node object in the linked list. You need a double pointer because you need to change pointer the pointer to newly the allocated head. C doesn't have *pass by reference*, so you need a double pointer to change where a pointer is pointing. `push` gets a pointer to the variable `node *head` of the `main` function.

Comment: oh im enlightened, i thought that when i use pointers that they are "automatically" called "by reference" because they store the memory address to what they point.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz sadly that's not the case, that's why you need double pointers. I've made an update of my answer once again, check it out